# Converting into correct format using GDAL

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I am trying to use gdal to convert landcover .tiff files into .asc files in the AAIGrid format.  I am using them for an application which seems to only accept formats where the xllcorner and yllcorner are in decimal degree format.  I can successfully translate the files into .asc using gdal_translate but am running into issues with gdalwarp.  The files I obtain online all give xllcorner and yllcorner as large doubles but not decimal degree.

I am trying to go from this:

[image]

To something like this (lat-longs are made up for example purposes):

[image]

I have been trying to use the function gdalwarp but I keep getting an error:

[image]

Can can someone assist me in getting these files into the right format?

Here is a report from running gdalinfo:

[image]

Comment: Your source data cannot be in EPSG:9001 https://epsg.io/9001. Try to find out what is the correct CRS.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The source data appears to be in 9001, is there a way to change this?  I downloaded these files from https://www.mrlc.gov/viewer/, and have also tried earthexplorer and a few more.  Is there an alternate open source of land cover data I should use or a way to convert these even though the axis are in EPSG:9001?

Comment: Please run gdalinfo for one of your source TIFF files and add the report into your question.

Comment: gdalinfo report added above

Comment: Ok, I downloaded also some data and understand now. There is indeed number 9001 in the metadata `LENGTHUNIT["metre",1, ID["EPSG",9001]]]]` but in that place it means the code of the unit of length, that is, metre https://epsg.org/unit_9001/metre.html?

Comment: Ok I see, there are different EPSG's listed for each parameter, but which one should I reference in gdalwarp, or does it matter?

Comment: Remove the `-s_srs` parameter from your command, gdalwarp can recognize the coordinate system automatically just like gdalinfo can. It may also be that there is not a registered EPSG code for the whole PROJCRS["Albers_Conical_Equal_Area" with that set of other parameters.  The PROJCRS code is now missing totally. If it was included it would appear last.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Error messages and code should be posted as text, not as a screenshot. It is very difficult to read for some users and impossible for screen readers, and google. Please take the [tour] to see how this site works.